# "ifconfig" or "ip a" not found when running jenkins script

Tags: linux, bash, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a task created in Jenkins where a Linux bash script should be runned. There is an ipconfig inside the script to capture the ip address.
The problem is when running manually in a linux terminal the commands works fine but inside Jenkins I am getting command not found.
During my research about the problem, I changed to ip a command but had the same issue.
Do you have an idea why this happens with jenkins?

Thanks

Comment: Probably /sbin is not added to $PATH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that it wasnt in the $PATH. You could try replacing each instance with the absolute path.